# How to use graphics(Piant component) on any one layer of JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to draw a line at run time on any one layer of JlayeredPane. What i am currently facing is that line drawn getting erased automatically once i release the mouse. I want that drawn line to be there until i click the mouse again.

I am calling the below written class, this way

```
    iDimension = new getDimension();
    iDimension.setBounds(1, 12,  441, 380);
    //iDimension.setOpaque(true);
    iDimension.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,100));
```

I have added iDimension With Layered pane in this way

```
    layeredPane.add(iDimension, new Integer(1),0);
```

Here is the getDimension Class

```
public class getDimension extends JPanel {

    public getDimension() {
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("ComboBox.border"));
        this.repaint();
    }

    Point pointStart = null;
    Point pointEnd = null;

    {

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                pointStart = e.getPoint();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                pointStart = null;
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                pointEnd = e.getPoint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                pointEnd = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (pointStart != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);
            //  System.out.println("" + pointStart.x +"," + pointStart.y +"," + pointEnd.x +"," +pointEnd.y);
        }
    }
}
```

I am a newbie in java. Kindly correct if there is any ambiguity in my question.

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Comment: Side note: don't draw in a JPanel's paint method but rather its paintComponent method, and be sure to use the `@Override` annotation above any method that you think is an override.

Comment: Side note 2: you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i am currently facing is that line drawn getting erased automatically once i release the mouse. I want that drawn line to be there until i click the mouse again.

The code is only doing what you tell it to do:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        pointStart = e.getPoint();
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        pointStart = null;
    }
});
```

and:

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); 
        if (pointStart != null) {  // *********
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);
        }     
    }
```

Note that if pointStart is `null`, you don't draw the line -- but you set it to null on mouseReleased! Solution -- don't do that.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GetDimension extends JPanel {

    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private Point pointStart = null;
    private Point pointEnd = null;

    public GetDimension() {
        this.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("ComboBox.border"));
        this.repaint();

        MouseAdapter myMouse = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                pointStart = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                pointEnd = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        };

        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (pointStart != null && pointEnd != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawLine(pointStart.x, pointStart.y, pointEnd.x, pointEnd.y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GetDimension mainPanel = new GetDimension();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GetDimension");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what should i change in my code so that it serves my purpose.

Comment: @Amit.D: I told you, get rid of the offending line. Don't set pointStart to null.

Comment: But that changed my starting point for next line to be drawn to the location where i released my mouse.

Comment: @Amit.D: no it shouldn't do that. See example code above for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. And thanks for some valuable suggestion ! Appreciate your effort!